# How do I store an Integer variable in android studio app, and retrieve it.?

Tags: java, android

I basically need the count value to be stored somewhere, and get retrieved when the app opens again.
Pls suggest an easy way
and I also like to include a message to users to visit the app after 30 minutes to click again.
I have altered the code per your suggestions, and its working fine, but the values get updated only on exiting and reopening the app. It doesn't update the value in realtime.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
//SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
private Button watchButton;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "myprefs";
public static final  String value = "key";

// int myInt = prefs.getInt("myInt", 0);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final int i = sharedpreferences.getInt(value, 0);
    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-02434841XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX");
   // mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    watchButton = findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    watchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Listen for when user presses button
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            // If a interstitial is ready, show it
            if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();

            }
            else
            {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
            // Otherwise end this activity (go back to first activity)
        }
    });
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
           // mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            int count = i;
            count += 1;
            TextView tv_data=findViewById(R.id.disCount);
            tv_data.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt(value, count);
            editor.apply();
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            // Load the next interstitial.

        }

    });
}

}
```

Comment: You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putInt("myInt", 12345);
 editor.apply();
```

and retrive it when you want :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesName", MODE_PRIVATE); 
int myInt = prefs.getInt("myInt", 0); // 0 is default
```

Comment: This is the best way. SharedPreferences is ideal for storing simple primitives as key value pairs.

Comment: I have altered the code per your suggestions, and its working fine, but the values get updated only on exiting and reopening the app. It doesn't update the value in realtime.

Comment: Are you sure that you get your value by prefs.getInt("myInt", 0); ?

Comment: yeah,bcoz, even after I close the App and reopen it, the value isn't affected. That means the value is returned by the prefs.getInt right?

Comment: Yes, if you don't change it, it is saved even you quit your app

Comment: and if you save you int as "myInt", you have te retrieve it using the same name

Comment: But right now, the count is not updated. Each time I close the app and open it again and click the button, the value gets incremented. If I am inside the app and click the the button many times , its not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save this value in the database and fetch this value when you open it. To send a message, read about alarm manager in the official documentation.

[Alarme Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

Answer (score 0):

- best way is [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)
  and this the best tutorial for use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)
- to include a message to users to visit the app after 30 minutes to click again

**you have multi way**

send [Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification) from the background after 30 min countdown [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask)

or by Toast in background and more than this